# Double-clicking edit links brings up multiple edit sections in questions and answers

Tags: bug, inline-editor

I happened to have a slow response when I clicked on "edit" for a question. Rather than wait any longer, I just clicked it again (don't ask why). At some point after editing the question, I was staring at two edit sections for that answer, one with my changes and one with the question in its original state. This appears to affect both question edits and answer edits.

Browser: Windows Chrome "19.0.1084.56 m"

#### Question double edits

When I went to reproduce the issue, it didn't show the second question edit section immediately. But, when I hit the only visible cancel button, a second edit section popped into place with some messed up Markdown UI, as seen in this shot.

[image: Sample screenshot of edit question display issue after multiple clicks]

In another attempt to reproduce, I was able to click the edit link three times. Again, everything looked fine until I clicked cancel. This time, there were two edit sections with messed up Markdown UI (no screenshot).

#### Answer double edits

I gave things a test on editing answers, too, and ran into some similar wonkiness. This particular attempt to reproduce resulted in two immediate edit sections, one with a messed up Markdown UI and with a populated Markdown preview and one with no Markdown UI and an empty Markdown preview.

[image: Sample screenshot of edit answer display issue after multiple clicks]

Comment: Behavior replicated on Firefox 13.0.1 on Linux.

Comment: I was able to replicate in IE 9.0.8112.16421 as well.

Comment: I've seen similar display artifacts that I don't think are necessarily app code-related. For example occasionally while editing a question the preview will disappear and won't come back, but I've also seen weird overlays of duplicated content like in your screen shot. These look to me to be more artifacts related to redraw / video card than anything else, though I realize that is probably not the entire issue.

Comment: Given the later screenshot, I think the duplicate may be related. In that shot, the second edit screen has no Markdown UI with it. I didn't confirm, but it could be the duplicate UI is the one that should be with the duplicate edit section.